# Mini Ipad stolen. Have two iPads with the same iCloud

Tags: ipad

I have two iPads with the same iCloud. One of them was stolen. What happens if I clear the data? Both iPads will be cleared?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by 'clear the data'? Do you mean erasing the iPads through Find My iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

No - when iCloud sends an erase message, it is targeted to a specific device and not all devices in one account.